# Implementing an audio stream service similar to Spotify

Tags: networking, server, audio-streaming, tcp

### High Level Description

Let's say I have a client program (an iOS app in my specific case) that should communicate with a server program running on a remote host. The system should work as follows:

- The server has a set of indexed audio files and exposes them to the client using the indexes as identifiers
- The client can query the server for an item with a given identifier and the server should stream its contents so the client can play it in real time
- The data streamed by the server should only be used by the client itself, i.e. someone sniffing the traffic should not be able to interpret the contents and the user should not be able to access the data.

From my perspective, this is a simple implementation of what Spotify does.

### Technical Questions

- How should the audio data be streamed between server and client? What protocols should be used? I'm aware that using something on top of TLS will protect the information from someone sniffing the traffic, however it won't protect it from the user himself if he has access to the encryption keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The data streamed by the server should only be used by the client itself, i.e. someone sniffing the traffic should not be able to interpret the contents…

HTTPS is the best way for this.

> …and the user should not be able to access the data.

That's not possible.  Even if you had some sort of magic to prevent capture of decrypted data (which isn't possible), someone can always record the audio output, even digitally.

> From my perspective, this is a simple implementation of what Spotify does.

Spotify doesn't do this.  Nobody does, and nobody can.  It's impossible.  If the client must decode data, then you can't stop someone from modifying how that data gets decoded.

### What you can do

- Use HTTPS
- Sign your URLs so that the raw media is only accessible for short periods of time.  Everyone effectively gets their own URL to the media.  (Check out how AWS S3 handles this, for an excellent example.)
- If you're really concerned, you can [watermark your files on-the-fly](http://audiowatermarking.info/), encoding an ID within them so that should someone leak the media, you can go after them based on their account data.  This is expensive, so make sure you really have a business case for doing so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's pretty much what I was looking for.